# Couchbase lite .net SDK Replication Error

Tags: wpf, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm working with couchbase lite .net sdk, and I got a example from below [url](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-training-todo).
and my configuration file is like below.

```
{
"log": ["HTTP+"],
"adminInterface": "0.0.0.0:4985",
"interface": "0.0.0.0:4984",
"databases": {
    "db": {
        "server": "walrus:data",
        "bucket": "todo",
        "users": {
            "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] }
        }
    }
}
```

}
when I run the wpf app, I'm getting error like below image.

[image](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mystorage-ded50.appspot.com/o/Untitled.png?alt=media&token=fe97119a-83a8-4a0c-9aaf-5bf958a0e8bd)
Please help me, I'm not sure how to implement couchbase sync gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
I add shadow property to configuration json file.
You can read more information from these links.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile-couchbase/NWd8xqPOjsc
https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/wiki/Bucket-Shadowing

```
{
 "interface": ":4984",
  "adminInterface": ":4985",
  "log": [ "*" ],
  "databases": {
    "sync_gateway": {
      "server": "walrus:",
      "bucket": "sync_gateway",
      "users": {
        "GUEST": {
          "disabled": false,
          "admin_channels": [ "*" ]
        },
        "user": {
          "admin_channels": [ "*" ],
          "password": "user"
        }
      },
      "sync": `function(doc){ "channel(doc.channels); }`,
      ,
      "shadow": {
        "server": "http://couchbase-dev.thisisdmg.com:8091",
        "bucket": "sales_agent"
      }
    }
  }
}
```